# How to update multiple documents in mongodb native nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Salam (means hello) :)

I'm running mongodb 2.4.8 and [Mongo DB Native NodeJS Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/). when I use the following function, only first document that matched `query` updates. how can I update all matching documents?

```
function update(coll, query, update, callback){
    var options = options || {};
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbName', function(error, db) {
        if(error){
            return console.dir(error);
        }
        db.collection(coll).update(query, update, {w:1}, function(error, result) {
            callback(error, result);
        });
    });
}
```

I installed my mongodb driver via `npm install mongodb` command, which installs version `1.3.23`, does this driver version support multi update? if not, how can I install a newer version of driver supports multi update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `multi` [option](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#update-options) in your `update` call to update all matching docs instead of just the first one:

```
db.collection(coll).update(query, update, {w:1, multi: true}, callback);
```

Comment: thanks, I also found [another document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) for update function which doesn't need neither callback function nor {w:1}, can you explain their difference?

Comment: @NasserTorabzade That doc is for the Mongo shell, not the node.js driver.  But you likely don't need `w:1` in your code, either.

Answer (score 3):

You can call updateMany to achieve this:

```
db.collection(coll).updateMany(query, update, callback);
```